# How to Vertically center h1 text on its background image?

Tags: html, css, image, center, vertical-alignment

I need the h1 text to be in the middle of its background image vertically.

```css
/* Header Container image */

.header {
  background-image: url("https://content.codecademy.com/courses/web-101/unit-6/htmlcss1-img_burgerphoto.jpeg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 420px;
}


/* Header Itself */

.header h1 {
  background-color: rgba(5, 168, 170, 0.6);
  color: #FFF;
  max-width: 165px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>BBQ BACON BURGER</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Use line-height:420px

Comment: Use top: 50%; position: relative; transform: translateY(-50%);

Comment: @SteveTomlin sorry that didn't work for me. Not sure why. It only heightens the background color of the text without vertically centering it.

Comment: @GrazielleCarvalho Thank you ! That works !

Comment: @mmirbekian You're welcome ;D